# How to select dates after three dates from current date using ajax control kit

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How can i disable all future dates after three days from current date (Today) in AJAX control kit

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" class="form-control"
      required="This Field is Required" AutoComplete="off"></asp:TextBox>                                                            

        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" 
    runat="server" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="checkProjectEndDate"
 TargetControlID="txtEndDate" Format="dd-MMM-yyyy"></ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>



<script type="text/javascript">
     function checkProjectEndDate(sender, args) {
     if (sender._selectedDate >= new Date()) {
     alert("You can not select a future date than today!");
     sender._selectedDate = new Date();
     sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
       }
      }
</script>
```

Its not allowing to select future date then today but i want something that i can select three day latter from today let me explain i want like user can not select any future dates after three days latter suppose today is 01-11-2019 so my calender's show only 03-11-2019 after 3Nov all date should not be visible

Comment: Here's an answered question about how to add days to a JavaScript date object: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date

Comment: i use but its showing Wed Nov 06 2019 23:41:30 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: i want like user can not select any future dates after three days latter suppose today is 01-11-2019 so my calender's show only 03-11-2019 after 3Nov all date should not be visible

Comment: Looks like @Fraddy has built that logic for you in his answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select date which is greater than 3 days:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3);
if(selected_date > date){
   // code here
}
```

Edit:
As per you question check below code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkProjectEndDate(sender, args) {

    var future_date = new Date();
    future_date.setDate(future_date.getDate() + 2);

    if (sender._selectedDate > future_date) {
      alert("You can not select a future date than today!");
      sender._selectedDate = new Date();
      sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: what should i add in OnClientDateSelectionChanged??

Comment: <script >
      var date = new Date();
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3);
      if (selected_date > date) {
      alert('can not select')
      }
 </script>

Comment: i used but no changes i found , Even its accepting all future dates

Comment: in your code, if date is greater than 3rd Nov then should if condition execute?

Comment: i checked function use alert('hi') for checking its working or not  but after this statement (sender._selectedDate > future_date)  i dint get alert message

Comment: yes if selected date greater then 3rd Nov then should if condition execute

Comment: update answer again. if you are not getting correct you will have to debug sender._selectedDate

Comment: Amazing .. now i set as i need thnx Fraddy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201733/discussion-between-fraddy-and-nits-patel).